# List of objects not added to the database with EFcore

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to make a simple program with .NET core that should save plugins and associated categories to a MySQL database.

These two classes exists:

```
public class Plugin
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string ProjName { get; set; }

    public string DownloadURL { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public string UniqueName { get; set; }

    public string PrettyName { get; set; }
}
```

I am using this Context:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Plugin> Plugins { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder
            .UseMySql(@"Server=XXX");
}
```

The simplified code (without HttpClient stuff) looks like this:

```
public static async Task GetPluginsOnPage(string baseUri)
{
    foreach (var plugin in pluginsOnPage)
    {
        List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();

        var nameHtml = "**";
        var descHtml = "**";
        var projName = "**";

        foreach (var x in plugin.***)
        {
            categories.Add(new Category() {PrettyName = "", UniqueName = "**" });
        }

        var downloadUri = "**";

        await Ctx.Plugins.AddAsync(new Plugin { Categories = categories, Description = descHtml, Name = nameHtml, ProjName = projName, DownloadURL = downloadUri });
    }

    await Ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Resulting database:

[image]

Note that 20 plugins have been added, but no categories.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. At the moment I overcome this by adding (in your case) the Categorie to the database first, with the FK property filled in when constructing the Category object.

I have no clue why this isn't working as it supposed to anymore...

EDIT: I was using/extending the ApplicationDbContext, creating a new one and using that fixed it for me.